# Remove extra sign up newsletter checkbox on one step checkout

Tags: checkout, newsletter, checkbox

I have two sign up to newsletter checkboxes on the last tab of my one step checkout. How do I get rid of only one of them?

I have inspected them both and they defined exactly the same way, but they work independently from each other. So if a customer doesn't wish to receive a newsletter, they have to uncheck both.

Has anyone found this before and have a solution.

Many Thanks

Bevan

Answer (score 0):

There may be a module that's adding it via a layout update, i'd check the layout xml's in your themes and the base theme to see if there is another newsletter signup reference somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the reply.

It gave some insight but led me to greater insanity. :0) 

While playing with them allowed me to remove both or none. the reference name in the xml  is checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after, so would assume that it should only place the code after the product details/totals. 

If I remove the before it loses both and same with the items.after

I I remove the getChildHTML functions ofr items_before or items_after in info.php it does the same or break and goes back to the view cart page.

I am not sure if I am on the right track its something else. 
Bevan

Comment: There could be another layout xml somewhere within your theme targeting the same layout handles, possibly from a third party module. If you have an IDE like PHPStorm you could do a search of all files within the design/frontend folder for the layout handle or the child block name/reference.